# How to parse escape characteres inside JSON value?

Tags: java, json, csv

I'm trying to create a JSONParser that will convert JSON keys and values from two JSON files (one in English and one in Portuguese) to a CSV.

However, when the CSV is generated, the escape characters still appear in text. I'm using Oracle’s JSONP. How can I parse the escape characters? Do I have to use other library?

**Example**

**key:**"validation.msg.calendar.repeating.cannot.be.blank": **value(inPortuguese):**"\"Repetindo\" não pode ser em branco.",

**The output to the CSV file is:** \"Repetindo\" não pode ser em branco.

The library is not parsing the escape for the ".
Thank you!

```
public class JSONParser {
    private String DELIMITER=",";
    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Termo"+DELIMITER+"Inglês"+DELIMITER+"Português\r\n");
    private Writer wrt;
    private JsonObject obj1, obj2;
    private HashMap<String, String> hm1, hm2;
    private Iterator<String> it1, it2;

    public JSONParser(InputStream fis, InputStream fis2) {
        obj1 = readJson(fis);
        obj2 = readJson(fis2);
        it1 = getIterator(obj1.keySet());
        it2 = getIterator(obj2.keySet());
        hm1 = createHashMap(obj1, it1);
        hm2 = createHashMap(obj2, it2);

    }

    public HashMap<String, String> createHashMap(JsonObject obj, Iterator<String> it) {
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String key = it.next();
            hm.put(key, obj.get(key).toString());
        }
        return hm;

    }

    public JsonObject readJson(InputStream fis) {
        JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(fis);
        JsonObject obj = reader.readObject();
        reader.close();
        return obj;

    }

    public Iterator<String> getIterator(Set<String> keys) {
        Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
        return it;
    }

    public void generateCSV(String filename) throws IOException {
        wrt = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filename), "ISO-8859-1"));
        Set<String> keys = obj1.keySet();
        Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String key = it.next();
            if(key.startsWith("#")) continue;
            String pt = "";
            if (hm2.get(key) != null)
                pt = hm2.get(key).toString();
            sb.append("\""+key+"\"" + DELIMITER + hm1.get(key).toString() + DELIMITER + pt +"\r\n");
        }   
        wrt.write(sb.toString());
        wrt.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What "escape characters" are you talking about? Could you show us sample input and output?

Comment: just added an example! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is most likely here:

```
hm1.get(key).toString()
```

If this is the [JsonValue.toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonValue.html#toString--) we are talking about, your problem is that it is overridden to return the JSON String, not the parsed value.

The docs of [JsonObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) recommend to use

> In the above example 2, "John" can be got using
>
> `String firstName = object.getString("firstName");`

Comment: So how can I return the parsed value? Is there a method like JsonValue.returnValue?

Comment: I used the .toString() because I don't know other way to return the text, so that I can export it to the CSV

Comment: Can't test this right now, but I suspect you need to invoke `JsonString.getString()`

Comment: You deserve all the credit, that worked like a charm! thank you so much!